# Camera app in Android without using intent

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

i am developing an android app where i am trying to implement the camera functionality, without using the intent to avoid getting android built-in camera.

I am using Preview.java to display what the camera see's on the screen.

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        Mydcamera = Camera.open();

        try {

            Mydcamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

            Mydcamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                    try {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));  
                        outStream.write(data);
                        outStream.close();

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
                        Preview.this.invalidate();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But Each time i run the app, i am getting force close on the below line of code

```
    Mydcamera = Camera.open();
```

**Error Log:**

```
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setup(Native Method)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:294)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:271)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at com.ssn.newcamerademo.Preview.surfaceCreated(Preview.java:45)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:564)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:408)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:352)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1646)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1644)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1373)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6936)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:357)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1904)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1527)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1263)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
     08-14 09:10:57.027: E/AndroidRuntime(2318):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Not getting where iam going wrong.  Please Help! Thanks!

Comment: You need to post the log cat, also, have you added the 'camera' permission to your manafest?

Comment: Using the camera directly is rather complicated to get right. You might consider [my CWAC-Camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera), either to use directly, or to use as a source of ideas for your own implementation.

Comment: mention the camera permissions in manifest file

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with the error log. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have all the required permissions set in the manifest file. From [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

If this guess didn't help you you'll have to provide more information like the logcat info.